# Unable to make RecyclerView Width as match parent

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Recycler View is only occupying 1st half of the screen no matter what I do.
Can anyone suggest how to make Recyclerview occupy full width of the screen?

This is what it displays me in Android Studio

[image: this is what it displays me in Android Studio]

But this is the actual output on a device. It's all wrapped to the left side of the device.

[image: but this is the actual output on a device. It's all wrapped to the left side of the device.]

**activity.java**

```
public class RecordLogs extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecordsAdapter adapter;
private List<Record> recordList;
private ProgressBar progressBar;

private FirebaseFirestore db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_record_logs);

    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar);


    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager((this)));
    recordList = new ArrayList<>();


    adapter = new RecordsAdapter(this, recordList);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
```

**activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".RecordLogs">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

    <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**row.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="15sp"

                tools:text="26/7/2018" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="Date"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/qty"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="15sp"


                tools:text="5" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="Qty. L"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/rate"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="15sp"


                    tools:text="25" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:text="Rate ₹"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/total"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="15sp"

                    tools:text="125" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:text="Total ₹"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**adapter.java**

```
public class RecordsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecordsAdapter.RecordViewHolder> {

private Context mCtx;
private List<Record> recordList;

public RecordsAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Record> recordList) {
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
    this.recordList = recordList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecordViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.record_logs_card, null);
    return new RecordViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecordViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Record record = recordList.get(position);
    holder.date.setText(record.getDate());
    holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(record.getQty()));
    holder.rate.setText(String.valueOf(record.getRate()));
    holder.total.setText(String.valueOf(record.getTotal()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return recordList.size();
}

class RecordViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView date, qty, rate, total;


    public RecordViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        qty = itemView.findViewById(R.id.qty);
        rate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rate);
        total = itemView.findViewById(R.id.total);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: remove this line `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);`

Comment: @Vucko Thank you for your comments, however it still remains fixed to the left and not responding to the available width real estate, even in landscape mode. I've just added adapter.java for you to have a look.

Comment: Ah I see that it was a problem with the adapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it:

All I had to change the following line of code in my custom adapter as follows:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.record_logs_card, null);
```

to

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.record_logs_card, parent, false);`
```

Comment: You found it but can You explain?

Comment: @deadfish Might be a bit late, but here: The inflated View cannot match its parents width without knowing what the parent view ist. Passing it "null" means you are trying to match "nulls" witdh, when setting "match_parent". "false" as value for "attachToRoot" ist needed as its forbidden to attach the view to the viewholder inside a recycler vier per documentation.